# Free mind mapping software that supports RTL text

Tags: windows, gratis, mind-mapping

Currently I am using Freeplane, but as you can see in the image, Hebrew text aligns to left.

Do you know about an alternative that supports RTL?

[image: Freeplane screenshot, showing Hebrew text]